# Find the top K elements in O(N log K) time using heaps

Tags: algorithm, heap, heapsort

Let's say if i have a list containing:

```
lst = [4,0,8,3,1,5,10]
```

and I'm planning to use a heap structure to help me retrieve the top k largest number where k is a user input.

I understand that heap sort is O(N log N) where we first take O(N) time to place them in a min/max heap and the O(log N) time to retrieve elements.

But the problem I'm facing now is that I'm required to retrieve the top k users in O(N log K) time. If my k is 4, i would have:

```
[10,8,5,4]
```

as my output. The thing I'm confused about is, at the early stage of forming the heap, am i supposed to heap the entire list in order to retrieve the top k elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `log K` term would suggest that you would only want a heap of size `K`. Here is one possible solution.

Start with an unsorted array. Convert the first `K` elements to a min-heap of size `K`. At the top of the heap will be your smallest element. Successively replace the smallest element with each of the remaining `N - K` elements in the array (that do not constitute a part of the heap), in `O(log K)` time. After `O(N)` such operations, the first `K` elements in the array (or, the `K` elements of the heap you created) will now have the `K` largest elements in your array.

There are other solutions but this is the most straightforward.

Comment: @COLDSPEED brilliant! So converting first k elements to a min heap of size k means, if my k is 3, i first convert the numbers [10,8,5] first into a min heap? Is that right?

Comment: @Maxxx No. If you did that, you have already got your final answer (the largest k elements), which requires you to sort the entire list.

Comment: @maxxx Instead, you first populate the heap with the first k elements with respect to their ordering in the list (not their values). So in our case, [4,0,8]. Then, with each subsequent item, in order to keep the heap size as k, you need to make a decision whether to add the new item to our heap (by evicting the smallest item from the heap) or simply ignore it (if it is smaller than the smallest item, thus smaller than all items in the heap). In other words, each new contender only needs to beat the smallest item to win a spot in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    for (int i : your_arraylist){
       pq.add(i);  //add to queue

      if(pq. size() > k){
         pq.poll();   //remove the top element, smallest in this case, once the queue 
                     // reaches the size K
       }
    }
System.out.println(pq);
```